# Template override not being used

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

Magento 2.2.7

I've placed my version of Wishlist list.phtml in my template directory at

```
/app/design/frontend/Local/argento-stripes-custom/Magento_Wishlist/template/item/list.phtml
```

However, this is not being used. Template hints shows its calling the default Magento Block & templates, vis

```
/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/list.phtml 

Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items
```

If I use a layout file to declare my my phtml file then I get an error about data not being available;

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist" >
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Wishlist::item/list.phtml</argument>
       </action>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Do I have to declare my own module to override Magento's Wishlist?

Comment: you don't need to override layout,if you overriding default magento theme file in your custom theme then it should automatically reflect

Comment: please do compile, upgrade, deploy and clear cache in this order,may be it will work

Comment: As per as, my idea your reference name is  wrong .it should be `customer.wishlist.items` instead of ``customer.wishlist`



`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist" template="YourTemplatefile" />
</page>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /app/design/frontend/Local/argento-stripes-custom/Magento_Wishlist/template/item/list.phtml

The reason your template is not being used is becasue your path is incorrect, you are specifying **template** not **templates** if you change this your overwrite should work fine

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest oversights! Thanks for your help here.

Comment: @Freshwebs glad your issue is resolved

Comment: This is one of the minor annoyances re: Magento. We have layout, which can contain multiple files, & templates, which might contain a single file. Shouldn't they all be plural??